# How to get rid of unwanted space in a Chromium Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm quite new to html 5 and css 3 but I wanted to make project page with flexbox and ran into a problem:
The site looks good in desktop mode but when it switches to the mobile view and "flex-flow: column" there is way too much space between the items as you can see in the pictures below. 
[Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1cFu.png)
[Smartphones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAhJd.png)
The problem only occurs in chromium based browsers (Google Chrome, Vivaldi, Iron, Opera) Firefox, IE and Edge work well.
I'm not allowed to post images yet so I just put the links here.
Down there you can see my CSS code. I hope some can help me with this!

```
body {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: f4f4f4;
font-family: Hind, Sans-serif;
justify-content: space-between;
}
header,
nav,
nav a,
article,
aside,
footer {
border-radius: 0px 0,5em 0em;
padding: 15px;
margin: 0.5em;
flex: 1 100%;
}
header {
background: var(--color-primary);
display: flex;
flex-flow: column;
align-items: center;
}
header * {
flex: 1 1 0%;
}
header nav {
flex: 1 1 100%;
}
nav,
nav ul,
nav li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
}
nav ul {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
nav li {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 1.3em 0;
flex: 1 1 100%;
}
nav a {
display: inline-block;
width: 95%;
/*background: #fffbf0;*/
border-bottom: solid 0.1em;
border-color: var(--color-primary);
margin: 0;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
color: var(--color-secondary-2);
}
@media all and (min-width: 35em) {
header {
flex-flow: row wrap;
}
nav ul {
flex-direction: row;
}
nav li {
margin: 0 0.5em;
flex: 1 1 0%;
}
```

Now for the essential HTML part:

```
<header>      
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="item1.html">item1</a></li>
   <li><a href="item2.html">item2</a></li>
   <li><a href="item3.html">item3</a></li>
   <li><a href="item4.html">item4</a></li>
   <li><a href="item5.html">item5</a></li>
   <li><a href="item6.html">item6</a></li>
   <li><a href="item7.html">item7</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You need to post a working code snippet, not just the CSS

Comment: Just as a heads up, you likely don't need to add in the vendor prefixes for Chrome (webkit) when specifying flex displays. The feature is supported by default in webkit browsers, although there can be some irregularities with IE (that won't be mitigated with a prefix). Save some bytes!

Comment: @LGSon added the HTML, I hope it's understandable now
And I removed the vendor prefixes, thanks

Comment: The issue is not reproduced with the posted code, so not much we can do

Comment: @cjl750 the cjl looks fine but as soon as I put the code into my html file i get the problem again.<br>
please see [my link](http://foto-kallmeyer.bplaced.net/)

Comment: @LGSon as soon as I put the code in an HTML file the issue occurs again
[you should be able to see it here](http://foto-kallmeyer.bplaced.net/)

Comment: @TCharb Chrome hasn't been webkit for several years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you remove `align-items: center;` from the `header` rule

```
header {
  background: var(--color-primary);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  /*  align-items: center;              commented out */
}
```

and change to `flex: 1 1 0%;` instead of `flex: 1 1 100%;` in your `nav li` rule

```
nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 1.3em 0;
  flex: 1 1 0%;               /*  change basis to 0%  */
}
```

---

You also need to close your media query properly by adding its missing end bracket `}`

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution to it! I'm very happy now!